# Saving a visual element to a file

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to save a framework element into a file this way:

```cs
async Task SaveVisualElementToFile(FrameworkElement element, StorageFile file)
{
    element.Width = element.ActualWidth;
    element.Height = element.ActualHeight;
    //string fileName = "customphoto.jpg";
    var renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
    await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(element, (int)element.Width, (int)element.Height);
    var pixels = await renderTargetBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();
    using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
    {
        var encoder = await
        BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, stream);
        byte[] bytes = pixels.ToArray();
        encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
                             BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
                             (uint)element.Width, (uint)element.Height,
                             96,
                             96,
                             bytes);

        await encoder.FlushAsync();
    }
}
```

But the result is not as expected. Here's an example:

Original image :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1xxd.png]

Saved image :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7ZTU.jpg]

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method is quite ok, only pixels got shifted due to incorrect width/height. All you have to do is to use `renderTargetBitmap.PixelHeight` instead of `element.Height`. The problematic code should look like this:

```cs
encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
                     BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
                     (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelWidth, 
                     (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelHeight,
                     96, 96, bytes);
```